Does Preference Hedonism encompass other philosophies such as Stoicism?
From my understanding, Stoics believe that virtue is the main goal of life. They argue that living a virtuous life is what matters, and that choices we make should reflect that. Furthermore, they argue that external factors are not inherently good or bad, and that they ascribe meaning to those factors.
Secondly, preference hedonism is the same as hedonism in which individuals pursue pleasure as the highest human good, but in this case may have their own definition of pleasure. They also argue that the only intrinsic value that anything has is the pleasure that it creates or the pain that it minimizes.
If I have understood these two correctly, then would a Stoic fall under the category of a preference hedonist who defines pleasure to be virtue, and living a virtuous life? I struggle to see where the two would make different decisions or believe different things if they both ultimately derive pleasure from the living of a virtuous life in the long term.
Additionally, I ask if this is true then could you not define any other philosophy to also fall under preference hedonism if pleasure is defined correctly to match up with other philosophies?
I hope someone can help me understand if my understanding and assertion is correct, or if not, why so. Thank you in advance.
